# Pausing main game thread until an Activity is started, and has finished - Android

Tags: android, multithreading

In my game when the user completes a stage, I want the main game thread to pause/sleep/wait and a new activity to be launched called StageClear that displays information about points scored etc. After this has been displayed and the user has pressed continue I want the original game thread to resume where it left off. I have tried to implement this but have so far been unsuccessful, probably because I'm new to dealing with multiple threads and also the idea of synchronizing them.

I most recently tried to implement a shared package-visible object that could notify after wait was called on itself, but I am getting errors in eclipse so it won't even compile, I think because though the object is declared public in an inner class, it cannot be seen or recognised by my activity elsewhere in a file in the package.

I have already built both activities but my issue is getting the main game one to launch the other, and pause whilst it waits for this activity to finish, before the main game thread continues execution.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should try [start Activity for Result](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29)..

Comment: I can only call startActivity, not startActivityforresult in the run method of the thread?